# Scrape string of text from website with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-tag-manager

I would like to scrape a webpage and **just** return the GTM (Google Tag Manager) container ID (In the example below it would be GTM-5LS3NZ). The code shouldn't look for the exact container ID but rather the pattern as I will use it on muultiple sites.

So far I can search the head and print the entire piece of text containing GTM, but I don't know how to format the find and the regex together to just return GTM-5LS3NZ (In this example).

```
import urllib3
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

response = http.request('GET', "https://www.observepoint.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data,"html.parser")

GTM = soup.head.findAll(text=re.compile(r'GTM'))
print(GTM)
```

Note: The GTM ID can have 6 or 7 alphanumeric characters so I would expect the regex for the container ID to be something like ^GTM-[A-Z0-9] - I don't know how to specify 6 or 7 characters.

Clarification on what I am after.
If you run the code above you get the following.

```
["(function (w, d, s, l, i) {\n      w[l] = w[l] || [];\n      w[l].push({\n        'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),\n        event: 'gtm.js'\n      });\n      var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],\n        j = d.createElement(s),\n        dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';\n      j.async = true;\n      j.src =\n        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;\n      f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);\n    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-5LS3NZ');"]
```

Where all I want is GTM-5LS3NZ.

Comment: `^GTM-[A-Z0-9]{6,7}` should be the regex you're looking for.  IF that is what you're looking for you should have made that more obvious in your question.  You already seem to have scraping a string of text from a website with BS down pat, so your question title is inaccurate.  Something like "How to extract from string with regular expressions" would have been better, since regular expressions are what you are asking for help with.

Comment: Thanks. It is two parts though. Help with the Regex, then using the Regex to return the container ID from the page.

Comment: Should be `re.search("GTM-[A-Z0-9]{6,7}",GTM)` provided GTM is the string at this point

Comment: Can we see a link to the target site or at least an example of the HTML?

Comment: This is the target site: https://www.observepoint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked it out now, thanks to the help in the comments. This is what I was after:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

response = http.request('GET', "https://www.observepoint.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data,"html.parser")

GTM = soup.head.findAll(text=re.compile(r'GTM'))
print(re.search("GTM-[A-Z0-9]{6,7}",str(GTM))[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar a few days ago, and a quick rewrite gives me:

```
import urllib3
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

response = http.request('GET', "https://www.observepoint.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data,"html.parser")

pattern  =re.compile(r'GTM-([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,7})')
found = soup.head.find(text=pattern)
if found:
    match = pattern.search(found)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

This gives me GTM-5LS3NZ as output.

Answer (score 0):

You could also extract from appropriate comment

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

r = requests.get('https://www.observepoint.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
for comment in soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)):
    if 'iframe' in comment:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(comment, 'lxml')
        id = soup.select_one('iframe')['src'].split('=')[1]
        print(id)
        break
```